# Need to code a category overflow feature for my sites homepage (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I’m running a website on Wordpress and utilizing the latest version (7.6) of the Bimber theme.

I’d like to create a custom php page if need be for this.

As you can see in the photos, the elements of what I’m trying to do are:

- responsive category layout to place on the home page of a wordpress site
- thumbnail with clickable category title (centered at bottom of thumbnail)
- on hover filter application to thumbnail listing out the pertinent
- posts under each category (bulletin list), that cut off at 5 items
- below the cutoff point, a ‘+’ number of posts in that category (i.e. +15)
- on-hover of bottom element (i.e. +15) the box/lists expands to a scrollable list of all items
- the bottom element (i.e. +15) turns into “Go to Category” link, takes user to said category.

I understand there is CSS involved in this as well.

I’m not a complete beginner, but for the sake of me really advancing my learning, assume that I am.

I truly appreciate all the help, and am happy to provide as much more info as needed,
I know this may not be nearly enough to go off of, and I’m happy to continue the convo with anyone who can help me code this.

[image: desired_layout_onhover]

[image: desired_layout]

Comment: _“I’m not a complete beginner, but for the sake of me really advancing my learning, assume that I am.”_ - gladly, but this can IMHO only mean voting to close as “Needs more focus.” Please go read [ask]. We don’t write custom tutorials on request on this site; _you_ need to start by showing some initial efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to create a custom template page for this and first get the parent category list and then you will have to call subcategories for each. the "+" button part can be done through javascript.

You need some PHP knowledge for this unless you find the correct plugin.